# Обязательна ли MVC веб архитектура?

Tags: mvc

Я новичок в php, mysql. И интересует сильно вопрос. Обязательно MVC архитектура? Возможно такой вопрос, потому что я досихпор не понял для чего она, и где и когда использовать.

Зачем её использовать? Если можно просто вызывать страницу Catatlog.php, а там уже отображать какой то каталог под id, вот так: $id = $_GET['id']; И вызываем например форму под id из базы данных.

**Можете просветить меня где используется MVC, служит ли он для защиты какой нибудь?
Все что я понял, человек делает запрос на Controller, тот вызывает например страницу который пользователь ввел, а после этого, страница(файл.php) вызывает какой либо метод. Все что я понял!**

Comment: Никакие паттерны не обязательны. У каждого есть свое назначеие. Если весь ваш вебсайт из 1 странички состоит, то вообще без разницы, что использовать. MVC имеет смыл для более-менее крупных проектов, когда отдельные странички начинаются превращаться в машанину кода, MVC позволяет держать код более структурированным и более легким в понимании и поддержке.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо! Теперь начал серьезно лучше понимать. 
Можете уточнить по подробнее если не сложно, что значит превращение страниц в машинный код? Или вы имеете ввиду что очень много страниц, и у каждой есть свои вычисление.

Comment: А что на счет с регистрацией? Или входа, нужно ли применять MVC архетектуру? 
Или например создание очень много профилей людей. Типа: Человек заходит на какой то профиль, у каждого профиля есть свой id страницы (https://site.com/profile/id=9). И профиль нужно отображать. Вот что то подобное.
Или например создание отдельной панели. Например кто то админ, а кто то продавец, и у каждой странице свои функционалы. 
Или например человек создает свою тему, добавляет её и редактировать может только он?

Comment: Я написал "Мешанина кода", а не "Машинный код". У вас было когда то, что вас просят сделать сайт на одну страничку и вы прекрасно справляетесь. А потом вас просят сделать авторизацию и скрыть половину странички от неавторизованного юзера. Потом просят добавить админку, куда надо прпепраавить админа после входа. Потом оказыватся, что для разных юзеров надо показывать разные данные. И просьбы всё накапливаются и накапливаются и в итоге через год ваши страницы раздувает, код  в страницах становится нестабильным, для каждой новой фишки вы тратите дни, чтобы убедиться, что она ничего не сломает..

Comment: MVC, например, позволяет отделить разные виды ответсвтенностей. То есть он пытается, как и другие паттерны впрочем, сделать так, чтобы ваш код был более структурированным. Чтобы за конкретные вещи отвечали конкретные классы. Это делает чтение и изменение кода проще. Например, если вам надо поправить html, вы смотрите на View, если логику - вы смотрите в контроллер, а не тратие человекочасы чтобы найти все места на страничках, где надо поправить код.

Comment: @tym32167 очень и очень хорошо объяснили! Тут я понял, мне это нужно.
Пойду разбираться с ним. Вы достаточно хорошо умеете объяснять. Спасибо!

Comment: Не знаю, как в PHP, но, например, в asp.net mvc контроллеры/представления/модели ещё и переиспользуемые. Вы можете размещать представления на любых страничках, где вам понравится. Вы можете одну и ту же модель использовать как для отображения данных, так и для редактирования. Вы можете даже настраивать роутинг сайта (правила, по которым юзер будет переходить по страницам) отдельными настройками. То есть всё настолько разделено, что если вам надо что от добавить / изменить, вам не надо бегать по всему коду, вы просто смотрите в конкретный класс, который за конкретную вещь отвечает.

Comment: Хорошо! Только одно пугает.
Думаю что реализация MVC, роутинг, намного будут сложнее в реализации, чем просто писать страницы и бизнес логику без MVC. Но на будущие будет удобнее как я понял.

Comment: В этом и есть минусы. То есть смотрите. Вот если у вас сайт будет очень простой - то там вообще без разницы, что делать. Если в нем будут проблемы, вы его просто выкинете и перепишете. Добавление всяких паттернов всегда усложняет код на старте, но по мере добавления всяких фич в ваш сайт, без паттернов вы дойдете до точки, когда на переписывание всего сайта уйдет год или два, что является пустой тратой времени. Петтерны же позволяют продолжать держать код организованным. То есть да, в начале добавление паттернов усложняет систему, но при этом падает скорость роста сложности.

Comment: Вот специально для вас не поленился, [нарисовал картинку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvQzU.png). Вы видите, что сначала мешанина кода выигрывает, но после определенной точки она уходит в небо, становится неподдерживаемой. Сложность оганизованного кода растет гоарздо мадленнее.

Comment: Даже вот [такая картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWdcH.png) будет более верно отражать реальность. Я только оговорюсь, что мало просто бездумно клепать все паттернами. Надо знать когда их применять. Просто факт того, что система перегружена паттернами, не делает её лучше. Понимание где именно эта грань - понимание, когда надо добавлять паттерн и какой, а когда нет - приходит больше с опытом.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое! Очень хорошо вас понял. Спасибо за ваши графики. Думаю после того как вы мне объяснили, мне необходим MVC.
Так как я буду делать очень много страниц, панели других пользователей и взаимодействие с главной страницей. В общем то, будет очень много кода и страниц. Спасибо большое еще раз!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можете просветить меня где используется MVC, служит ли он для защиты
> какой нибудь?

В вашем конкретном случае страница (view) рендерится в контроллере(controller) с данными(model).

Так давайте не путать придали. MVC это паттерн как вы поняли, их много. Обязательна ли она? Ну если их много то можно ли предположить что не обязательно? Пример [MVP или MVVM](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.habr.com/ru/amp/post/215605/). По вопросу безопасности это другая пидаль и решают ее вне зависимости от выбранной вами архитектурной модели.

Comment: Хорошо, вас понял. Особенно вот это понятие: `В вашем конкретном случае страница (view) рендерится в контроллере(controller) с данными(model).`.
Сразу выстроился образ того, что представляет из себя MVC. Спасибо еще за источники. Буду читать

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Рад помочь

Comment: Если ответ вам помог то можете пометить как полезный. Под стрелками ответа галочка